# Aligning Label and TextBox in C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, user-interface

[image: Text in the Label is higher than TextBox]

In the image above the text in the label is higher than the TextBox on the right.

I have looked at the control properties but I could not find how to align the label text with the text box correctly so that they will be aligned in the center/middle together.

Is there any settings in the properties I need to do?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000731/how-do-i-align-a-textbox-and-label-in-tablelayoutpanel and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170315/align-textbox-and-label-text

Answer (score 2):

In the visual studio designer, for each row:
1. Select the textbox
2. Holding shift, select the corresponding label
3. On the toolbar, alignment options will become enabled. Click on align middles.

Repeat the above for the other rows.