# Is it possible to get your user control to display those alignment guides when placing them on a WinForm?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, windows-forms-designer

In Visual Studio (2008) when you place a textbox on a Windows Form, and drag it around, you see very helpful guidelines which help you align it (left, right, top or bottom) to other controls. You also see a line the represents the bottom of the text in that control helping you align the text within your textbox, to the text within a label, regardless of the height of that label.

I have user control that contains a textbox and a couple of buttons. Can I force the VS2008 designer to show me the same line for the bottom of the text, from the textbox within my user control? If so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like this answer might be what you need - [Baseline snaplines in custom Winforms controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93541/baseline-snaplines-in-custom-winforms-controls)

Comment: Thanks - and I searched before I posted too :-(   Sorry.